# Calling Excel from a Child Powershell script...losing context/session

Tags: powershell-2.0, export-to-excel

Ok due to requirements I have a main powershell that calls child powershell scripts using the & command. In two of my child powershell scripts I use Excel object to either read an excel file and/or create an excel file. If I run these files locally run great no problems. If I run them through a scheduler (in this case Tidal Scheduling Tool) I have issues.

Issue 1:
The first child script reads an excel file to get the names of the worksheets then uses the worksheet name to query the excel file using OleDB. The query function is in a utilities module and gives an error that it can not find the file or it is locked by another process. I've killed the excel process and still wasn't allowing me to query from the file. As a test I commented out the portion of the script that reads the file and hard coded the worksheet name and works fine so somehow the child script is not able to release the handle on the COM object/file.

Issue 2:
From a second child script I create an excel spreadsheet. I'm creating a csv file which I then save as xls file. Again works fine when running locally but when I run through scheduler I get an error when attempting to run the following line: [void]$worksheet.QueryTables.item($connector.name).Refresh and the error that I get is:

*Exception calling "Refresh" with "0" argument(s): "Excel cannot find the text f
ile to refresh this external data range.
Check to make sure the text file has not been moved or renamed, then try the re
fresh again."*

Again I'm calling these children scripts using the & command (i.e. & \scriptpath\script.ps1)

Anyone seen this before and know how I can make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. Looks like Tidal scheduler has Agents and some of the agents setup at my client will run my scripts with no problems while others will not create files or lock files with no real errors given. Anyway, sorry I don't have more than that but powershell is working fine. :)